# get the name of the new file in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
    #Config Variables
    $SiteURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Test-Reports"
    $FolderURL= "/Shared Documents/" #Folder's Site Relative Path
    $oldCount = 16
    function fileOps {


                    Try {
                            #Connect to PnP Online
                            Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
                          
                            #Get All Files from the Folder
                            $FolderItems = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File
                             
                            Write-host "Total Number of Files in the Folder:" $FolderItems.Count
                            if ($FolderItems.Count > $script:oldCount) {
                                                                         Write-host "I am here"
                                                                        } 
                            $oldCount = $FolderItems.Count  
                            ForEach($File in $FolderItems)
                            {
                                $File.Name
                            }
                        }
                    catch {
                        write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
                         }

}
For (;;) {
        fileOps 
        timeout 20
```

I am trying out powershell to get a list of files from my sharedpoint site. This lists number of the files there.I am struggling with the format though and am short on time. Once a new file is dropped, I want it to print out the name of the new file that is added and break out of this loop to call a python script. This function needs to run indefinetly.

```
While($TRUE)
      fileOps
```

Comment: `if $FolderItems.Count > $oldCount` --> `if ($FolderItems.Count -gt $oldCount)`. Plus, I think you need to instantiate variable `$oldCount` to 0 first and inside the function use `$script:oldCount`

Comment: @Theo I did..please check..Doesn't seem to work..updating the code in the question

Comment: No, you are still using `>` instead of `-gt`.

Comment: @Theo ..Sorry about that...It works. However, the $oldcount variable is not updating it's value...

Comment: Then try forcing variable `$FolderItems` to be an array so you can safely use its Count property. `if (@($FolderItems).Count -gt $oldCount)` and `$script:oldCount = @($FolderItems).Count`. Since you are not scoping `$oldcount` when setting its new value, then no.. it won't be updated, because for the function this is simply a LOCAL variable.

Comment: @Theo I figured that out..I had to map the new value to `$script:oldCount` . It updates. I work with python, so I have some idea of the logic, just need to translate that over to powershell..onto getting the new file name then. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comments:

- use `script:` scoping on your `$oldCount` variable inside the function, so it can update the value on that while it has been defined elsewhere
- Force the `$FolderItems` variable to always be an array. Arrays have a `.Count` property, single items do not

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Test-Reports"
$FolderURL= "/Shared Documents/" #Folder's Site Relative Path
$oldCount = 16

function fileOps {
    Try {
            #Connect to PnP Online
            Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive -ErrorAction Stop
                          
            #Get All Files from the Folder
            # use the `@()` construct to ensure you receive an array of items
            $FolderItems = @(Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File -ErrorAction Stop)
                             
            Write-host "Total Number of Files in the Folder:" $FolderItems.Count
            # PowerShell uses `-gt` operator for Greater Than, not the `>`
            if ($FolderItems.Count -gt $script:oldCount) {
                Write-host "I am here"
            } 
            # set the script-scoped variable to its new value
            $script:oldCount = $FolderItems.Count  
            # output the file names
            $FolderItems.Name
        }
    catch {
        write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
    }
}
```